# C# ConsoleApp injection startup?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a simple C# .NET Core 5 Console Application that I need to add dependency injection (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection) to. I know how to do this if it suppose to start a micro service but what If I want to just run it as a regular Console Application with DI?

I got this code :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceName =
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    var appSettings = configurationBuilder.Get<AppSettings>();

        Log.Information("{@serviceName} test starting up.", serviceName);
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseMyAppMQ(context => context.UseSettings(appSettings.MQSettings))
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services
                    .Configure<MQSettings>(configurationBuilder.GetSection("MQSettings"))
                    .AddTransient<ITestController>(s => new TestController());
            })
            .Build().Run();

        Log.Information("{@serviceName} test closing down.", serviceName);
}
```

I need a entry point where I can run my underlaying class run method, but how?

Regards

Comment: This is already provided in the worker template, and actually needs far less code. Run `dotnet new worker` and check the code. This creates a console application that starts all registered `BackgroundService`-derived classes. If you want to terminate the application when one of the services ends you'll have to tell the host by injecting `IHostApplicationLifetime` and calling `StopApplication()`

Comment: Inject your class with its interface (ie: .AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();). Then use middleware to call your class run method(ie: app.Use()). See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Otherwise, instead of calling `Run()`, just use `Build()` to get the host. Request a "service" explicitly from the host, call its methods and exit the application when finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `IHostedService` interface (or extend `BackgroundService` base class) and register it with `services.AddHostedService<YourServiceClass>()` or
`builder.Services.AddHostedService<YourServiceClass>()`, if using .NET 6 minimal API as described [in official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). In this case `IHostedService.StartAsync` will be your entry point.

However, it does seem very inefficient, if all you need is just a simple console app with DI. As @Panagiotis Kanavos suggests you can build the host without running it, because then you can use it as a wrapper around DI container and resolve any registered service. In this case the entry point for your code is the next line after you've built your host, where you can resolve any registered dependency with

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   ...
   .Build();
host.Services.GetService<YouService>()
```

But it is still an inefficient solution for just a console app, because you only need DI container, but not the entire host. Just use any third-party DI framework (like Autofac, Ninject or any other) instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. Their setup is usually [quite minimalistic](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html) and you will get just DI container with you services without anything else. You can still use configuration package and loggers, just register them in your container similarly to how you've done it before with UseXxxx methods.

Comment: Thanks, I whent with Autofac in this case.